# Infopath template to be used in different server

Tags: infopath, template

I am working on infopath designer and saved the template in a server. But now i need to use the same infopath form in different site in differnet server. How come i use the template in other server.

Comment: Do you find any solution for your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with a list form, then you cannot publish it to another server. A list form is tied to its list. You could export the list as a template and create another list based on that template on the other server.

With a browser form, you can save the xsn as a separate file. Then, instead of Quick Publish, go through the full Publishing steps, i.e. File > Publish > SharePoint Server and select the new server and library. You may also need to adjust data connections before you publish the form.

Do NOT use File > Info > Publish. That will do a quick publish to an existing location:

[image]

Instead, go the full publishing path from scratch: File > Publish > SharePoint Server etc.

[image]

Comment: I saved it as separate file..but when try to click publish it directly getting publish without asking any server...it takes the server site as the previous one site...and finaly error is shown

Comment: I added a few screenshots. What kind of form is it? Browser or list?

Comment: fully customized sharepoint list...ie8 browser

Comment: You cannot publish a list form to a different site. I've edited my answer to start with a suggestion regarding list forms.